# Allow only one decimal and only positive number in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have tried below code but it doesn't seem to be the perfect solution. Also, the keypress event does not work on mobile. I have tested on android google chrome. Please help if there is any perfect solution.

In HTML file I added keypress event.

```
<input type="text" name="xyz"(keypress)="numberOnlyWithDecimal($event,xyz)"[(ngModel)]="xyz">
```

In .ts file, I added this code.

```
numberOnlyWithDecimal(event, text): boolean {
    var regex = /^\d+(\.\d+)?$/;
    const charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    if (text) {
      var test = text.split(".")
      this.textLength = test.length - 1;
    }
    if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
      return false;
    }
    if (!regex.test(charCode)) {
      return false
    }
    if (charCode == 46 && this.textLength ==1 ) {
      return false
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: We very much encourage self-answered questions here. However, they have to be as good as ordinary questions - they cannot be brief and show no research just because the answer will be supplied immediately. Thus, we tend to say that asking good self-answered questions is rather hard, since it requires the author to remember what they didn't know, and what they were trying, before finding the answer themselves.

Comment: "perfect solution" is a vague thing. Please be more specific about problems with the current solution, otherwise it's unlikely that anybody will answer (or the question will be reopened). Describe what problems you see about your solution and ask a specific question

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Directive](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives) to implement that.

```js
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appInputOnlyDecimal]'
})
export class InputOnlyDecimalDirective {
  constructor(private ngControl: NgControl) {}

  @HostListener('input', ['$event.target.value'])
  public onInput(value: string) {
    // Your logic here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should do:

> input type="number" min="0" max="9"